# Oracle SQLDeveloper Table Name autocompletion setting

Tags: database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using `Oracle SQLDeveloper 2.1.1.64` version. Table Name autocompletion is not happening.

Checked in autocompletion settings but in vain.

Any ideas about it?

Comment: Did you try the current version? (which is 3.2)

Answer (score 35):

Though this post is old but still I see many people not able to get real **Auto Complete** intellisense feature because as soon as **Auto Complete values exceeds 10** then autocomplete doesn't work i.e you need to explicitly use *CTRL+SPACE* for displaying intellisense in that case.

Please follow the steps so that you will be not faced with this problem.

I'm using [SQL Developer 4.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-ea-42-3211401.html) at time of this demo. If you have some issues in upgrading to this version of SQL Developer from the past then you need to also update your JDK to 1.8 or above.

Please follow steps below to ensure that SQL Developer Auto Completion (intellisense) works in ALL cases.

**Step 1:** Open SQL Developer and go to **Tools -> Preferences**

**Step 2:** Select **Code Editor -> Completion Insight**

**Step 3:** Ensure that you have following settings as shown in snapshot below

[image: Snapshot for Enabling Auto Code Completion]

Comment: it still doesn't show up in a query having brackets ()

Comment: @Toolkit have you tried pressing `CTRL+SPACE` ? If still doesn't show up on pressing this key combination then it won't show by changing the setting as well.

Comment: yes, I tried Ctrl+Space. just weird that MySql has it all resolved and the most expensive db can't figure it out for so many years...

Comment: what is the force shortcut for a mac?

Answer (score 17):

Go to: `Tools > Preferences > Code Editor > Completion Insight`
And make sure your settings are configured properly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

SQL-Developer probably cannot lookup the completion fast enough on your database and therefore doesn't show it. You can use `CTRL-SPACE` to try forcing it.

Answer (score 2):

if nothing works, open a new worksheet. many a times that is the real problem. current worksheet has corrupted

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Version 18.4.0.376 Build 376.1900, Ctrl-Shift completion was ignored every time I had **any** worksheet statements (preceding the one I was trying to complete) that lacked a terminating semicolon or was not commented out.

Answer (score 1):

Tool > Preferences > Editor  > AutoReplace check Enabled and Create Definition File. AutoReplace definition file format should be **ssf = select * from**  and enter one item per line etc.  for Version 8.0.1.1498

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-SPACE works, but only before the intellisense dropdown shows up. I had to increase the time delay before it shows up so that it doesn't show up until after 4 seconds. this way, I have 4 seconds to hit ctrl+space to autocomplete