# Auto-Popup completion is not working in SQL Developer 4.2

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Auto-Popup completion is not working in SQL Developer 4.2 for SQL server database

Tried all the stuff mentioned in the internet i.e.

> Enabled the "Enable Completion Auto-Popup in SQL Worksheet" in the Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Completion Insight.

Below is the setting I had tried:

[SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOx47.jpg)

> Also tried using Space+Ctrl. But still nothing is working.
>   Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: you need to show us what you're trying, like the code in your editor that refuses to provide suggestions

Answer (score 2):

be SURE to

close your current SQL statement with a semicolon ;

even if, of course, it is not completed.

Within a real working env it is easy to write many statements in the same worksheet, so the Code completition get confused, and with errors it does NOT show.

[more hints [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578591/oracle-sqldeveloper-table-name-autocompletion-setting/55830945#55830945) : ]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution I did followed and resolved the issue of auto-complete.

**Step 1**: Open SQL Developer and go to **Tools** -> **Preferences**

**Step 2**: Select **Code Editor** -> **Completion Insight**

**Step 3**: Ensure that you have following settings as shown in snapshot below

Set the popup speed as 0.6 sec

Set 1000 matches.

Dictionary mode as CHACE_UNION

I am using SQL Developer version 19.2.... in lower version Dictionary mode may not be the option.

[image: Fix for auto-populate]

**Step 4**: While writing the query in worksheet, please try to get schema name first, which will boost the auto-popup.

**Step 5** : Always end the query with semi-colon.. just to make sure that previous query is ended properly and for the next query auto-popup works fine.

I did followed these and now I am not facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It will never work.

> > for SQL server database

The everyday database development, query, and admin features in Oracle SQL Developer are built exclusively for Oracle Database.

The SQL Server connectivity is available for one primary purpose - migrating those systems to Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is probably set as a shortcut for 'Completion Insight'. Change it to be the shortcut for 'Code Template'.

I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as a shortcut for 'Code Template' (auto completion) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> as a shortcut for 'Completion Insight' (template pop-up). Works nice.