# Dot lookup is not working in SQL developer even after enabling it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Completion insight is enabled in my sql developer but still it doesn't show up.
For example if I write a simple sql query:

When a table is aliased and if I use the alias in my query and enter dot then the columns in the tables are not listed. Eg: i.

select * from items i where i.item_type = 'Hat';

I tried pressing Cntrl+Enter and it also didn't work.

Appreciate your valuable inputs.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle SQLDeveloper Table Name autocompletion setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578591/oracle-sqldeveloper-table-name-autocompletion-setting)

Comment: It is not... The settings and everything is configured properly but still it doesn't work